# PHP var displays in Chrome Dev Tool, but not webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-devtools

I have this issue where, I can see the echo of a variable via the preview on Chrome Developer Tools, but it's blank on the actual web page.

I am guessing this is down to a timing issue, so to make it clear this is how I have it.

- As page (index.php) loads, it links a .js file that does a FLQ query on FB to get the users name.
- It then uses ajax to repost to the index.php with the information.
- Back at the index.php page, it reloads and collects via $_POST
- It then displays some of the user info held in $_POST

I am guessing why I am doing is not possible, but it's odd that in the Chrome dev tool, all the variables echo on the page, but the actual page is blank where the variable should display.

I can only suggest I have a holding page, collect the detail and then load then moves to the main page to display the data.

```
<!--
    Index.php
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
    <?php
    global $uid;
    global $una;
    global $uem;
    global $uph;
    ?>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">   </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // initialize the library with the API key
        FB.init({ apiKey: '2847xxxxxxxx689' });  
    </script>
    <?php
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response
        }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream'});

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/op.js"></script>
 <?php
 $uid = $_POST['uid'];
 $una = $_POST['una'];
 $uem = $_POST['uem'];
 $uph = $_POST['uph'];
 echo $_POST['una'];
 ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/op_main.css" media="Screen" type="text/css"   />
  <?php
    //include('assets/opPHP.php');
    include('sql/ajaxsql.php');
    include('sql/phpsql.php');
    $opapp = new opapp;
    ?>
  <body>
    <div id="mainbody">

        <div id="topbanner">
            Beta Name <?php echo $una; ?>
        </div> 


 <--

  .js File

  -->

        $(window).load(function() {

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                var query = FB.Data.query('select uid,name,email, pic_square from user     where uid={0}', response.id);
                query.wait(function(rows) {
                    var uid = rows[0].uid;
                    var una = rows[0].name;
                    var uem = rows[0].email;
                    var uph = '<img src="' + rows[0].pic_square + '>';

                    $.ajax({

                        url: '../index.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'uid=' + uid + '&una=' + una + '&uem=' + uem + '&uph=' + uph
                    });
                });

            });

        });
```

I can see it posts the information, so my question is.  Is their another way to collect the information, while being on the same page.  Even explain why I can see it it dev tool, but not the main page?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

`echo $_POST['una'];` is echoed in the head tag so it will be shown in Chrome dev tools but not in web page.

Regarding `<?php echo $una; ?>`, I am not seeing anyplace were this variable is getting set. So this may be the reason why it is coming blank

Comment: Reposted this:   The index.php makes the var global, then it runs the op.js file which is the second quote above, this gets the information and ajax posts it back to the index.php file.  it then reloads the index and the var are loaded

Comment: Coz, I can't see your output, please remove `echo $_POST['una'];` and again try checking if the value is still coming chrom dev tools.

Comment: I know it does, because there is another echo at the bottom of the page, and in the middle, and they all show up on Dev tools, but not on the main page. You have a div called topbanner, thats another echo also, and that shows, but again, only in the tool not the display page :(